# Mortgage/annuity spreadsheet formula question

Tags: spreadsheet

I use IPMT formula in google spreadsheets to compute interest payment after 1st month like this:

**IPMT**(annualRate/12, 1, loanYears*12, loanReceived) - this return for my specific case, 40568 loan for 3.52%, 22 years - **119**

Now I try to cumulate the interest (for 1 month) with following formula:
**CUMIPMT**(annualRate/12, loanYears*12, loanReceived, 1, 2, 0) - I receive **237**

They should represent the same thing isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I try to cumulate the interest (for 1 month) with following
> formula: CUMIPMT(annualRate/12, loanYears*12, loanReceived, 1, 2, 0) -
> I receive 237

That formula is calculating the first two months. That is why the answer, 237, is about double the 119 from the first formula.

Comment: Right ! I saw some examples and I had the impression I need to increase the second index in CUMIPMT for 1 month.